# Trouble creating a SWC file with exposed assets without Flash Professional

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, swc

'm currently trying to create a swc library that includes pngs and a few miscellaneous classes.  Note, I'm not using Flash Professional at all, only Flash Builder 4.7.  I've created an AS Library project. Put my supporting classes and pngs in the source folder.  Once I clean and create the swc, I decompress it and the images are in the swc, so I know they're being included.

Now I create a new AS Project, include the swc in my lib path and it shows up in my referenced libs, great.  When I twirl down to look at the contents, I only see the classes.

My question is how to I get to the raw pngs or any other assets (xml, css) that I include in the swc?

I tried creating an EmbeddedAssets class in the swc and pointing to the assets... and creating a const for the class.  This forces the it to show up in my project, but as something like image_name_png_4394434l32k39e393.abc.  It seems when taking this approach, Flash Builder appends a random string to the asset, which makes it much more difficult to target it, having to use getDefinitionByName()... not very elegant or useful.  In using this embed approach, is there a way to force Flash Builder to not add the random stuff?  Do I have to use Ant to build the swc to force the name properly?  If so, does anyone have an ant script or know of a tutorial that shows how to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help at all...

Comment: embed your assets in a static class and refer to them that way.

Comment: That's what I did using the Embedded Assets class and instantiating the const for each asset.  I get "Error: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor."  I'm instantiating from another class in the swc file.  The only way I've been able to instantiate the class is with the method above (using getDefByName).